# using sinatra on AWS how can I connect to an RDS postgres database?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sinatra, sequel

I want to deploy an app to AWS. I am using ruby, sinatra and postgresql. The postgres DB is setup independently of the app deployment (but hosted on Amazon).

I am using the sequel ORM.

In my app directopry I created a folder ".ebextensions" and then created a file "db.config" in the same directory.

The file is:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['db_name'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['db_user'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['db_password'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['routexxx.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['5432'] %>
```

and my Sequel connection string is:

```
DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://db_user:db_password@routexxx.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/niyan')
```

which appears in my app.rb file.

This works on my local machine (using ngrok) but not when pushed to AWS. I get an error message which says "504 Gateway Timeout".

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: What is the security profile on the Amazon DB? Who/what IP ranges are allowed to connect to it?

Comment: o.o.o.o/ as I say it works from my local machine and I can also connect, from the terminal, with psql, so the credentials are correct and the database is working. Just one user.

Comment: the purpose of the question is more towards: is the procedure that I have followed correct? It does not work so I have done something wrong. Thank you anyway fro your interest.

Comment: I've used Sequel to connect to an AWS DB before (though I was using MySQL) and this looks correct to me. The fact that you have no trouble connecting from your local machine makes me think it's related to the security group. I would also try connecting to the host IP instead of the domain name, just as a test. Hopefully someone else will have more insight.

Comment: thanks, I will look again at the security group.

Comment: For what it may be worth, I think that the problem may lie with the fact that it is a "free" RDS database and so in virtual private cloud. So you could be right in that it is to do with security level access. I am going to try to connect to a heroku db (which is really also an amazon db) and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks Shawn, you were right. It was because I was using the "free tier" so I could not access it in the normal way. If you use a non free database instance then all you need to do is include the following string in your app file: 
DB=Sequel.connect('postgres://user:pasword@url.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname') 
and you are good  to go, don't even need a config file.